# Cannot compare schemas with SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-schema

I'm trying to compare schemas with the sqldeveloper database difference tool. When it finishes from making the comparison (very fast) it tells me the following in all objects of the database:

> SCHEMA_NAME.MD5 using SCHEMA_NAME connection. Could not compare objects. Make >sure you have the necessary permissions.
>   You must own the objects or have the select_catalog_role

Both users have the select_catalog_role role. Am I missing any permissions to assign? Is there something wrong in my database?

Comment: Does the user you use to connect with sqldevelopr has select_catalog_role?

Comment: select catalog might not be enough, it often requires you be the schema owner itself or a higher privileged user

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem. It happens also if you check SQL tab (sql table crate script) in some table definition - shows empty screen.

I have tried step-by-step to execute the same SQL that SQL Developer executes (there is a "Statements - Log" in SQL Developer). There was 6 separate SQL statements and, finally, one of them gives me the correct error: "**ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP**".

Fixing this by extending the tablespace (for example by following: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240774/how-to-increase-size-of-temp-tablespace-in-oracle-12c-rac-with-asm) corrects this error, and some other misbehaviors.

Now I can generate SQL create script for a table, make a diff between schemas, etc.